# Clearing MDTextField from kivymd after submission

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to create a game which requires the user to input coordinates. However, I realise that the fields are not cleared even after the "Enter" button is clicked and the screen is changed. Usually using the normal textinput field, I can just insert a python line of `self.shootdepthinput.text=''`, which will clear the text input in the field as it's a string. However, for MDTextField, the input is in the form of a tuple, which is immutable. Does anyone know of a function for me to clear the MDtextfield? Thank you!

This is an extract of my kivy file where my MDTextField is found in:

```
<ComputerScreen>:

    shootxinput: shootxinput_id
    shootyinput: shootyinput_id
    shootdepthinput: shootdepthinput_id

    id: "computerscreen_id"
    name: "computer"
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: "battleshipgame.png"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        id: s_input
        pos_hint: {"x":0.03,"y":0.72}
        size_hint : 0.7, 0.1

        MDTextField:
            id: shootxinput_id
            hint_text: "X-Coordinate"
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            color_mode: "custom"
            helper_text: "Enter a number from 1 to 10"
            line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1

        MDTextField:
            id: shootyinput_id
            hint_text: "Y-Coordinate"
            required: True
            color_mode: "custom"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            helper_text: "Enter an alphabet from A to J"
            line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1

        MDTextField:
            id: shootdepthinput_id
            hint_text: "Depth"
            required: True
            color_mode: "custom"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            helper_text: "0: Surface Level, 1: Sub-sea Level"
            line_color_focus: 0, 0, 0, 1

    FloatLayout:
        id: buttonarea
        Button:
            id: shootsubmitbtn
            size_hint:0.1,0.05
            on_press: root.shoot()
            text: "Enter"
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.75, "y": 0.75}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a statement that clear the input field inside the `shoot` method

```
def shoot(self, *args):
    shootxinput_id.text, shootyinput_id.text = ""
    # do some other things
```

Comment: Hello! I have tried that, but for MDTextFields, shootxinput_id.text comes out as a tuple, which is immutable... Is there a way to clear a tuple?